# React useState not setting a variable correctly in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm encountering an issue with setting the state quizId correctly in a React component using useState and useEffect. Here's the breakdown of my code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import quizService from '../../features/quiz/quizService';
import QuizForm from "../../components/renderQuiz";
function RenderQuizPage() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const id = location.state?.id;
  const [quizData, setQuizData] = useState(null);
  const [quizId, setQuizId] = useState(null);

  const fetchQuizInfo = async () => {
    try {
      const videoData = {
        id: id
      }
      const data = await quizService.getQuiz(videoData);
      setQuizId(data.id);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching quiz info:", error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchQuizInfo();
  }, [id]); // Depend on id changes

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchQuizData = async () => {
      try {
        const data = await quizService.renderQuiz({ quizData });
        setQuizData(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching quiz data:", error);
      }
    };

    if (quizId !== null) { // Only fetch data if quizId is not null
      fetchQuizData();
    }
  }, [quizId]); // Depend on quizId changes

  return (
    <div >
          <QuizForm
              quizData={quizData}
          />    
    </div>
  );
}

export default RenderQuizPage;
```

The issue I'm facing is that the quizId state is not being set correctly within the fetchQuizInfo function. Despite the data.id being logged correctly in the console, the quizId state remains null in subsequent useEffect calls, leading to unsuccessful data fetching. How can I ensure that quizId is set correctly and triggers the useEffect for fetching quiz data? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: let's try and debug this more...if you add a simple use effect that is dependent on quizData and simply console.log(quizData) as well as logging 'data' in your existing use effect before the set is called. Then compare these and see if there are any differences and if so what are they? If not/if they are both the same and they are both logging as expected then maybe there is something missing or needed in the QuizForm component